# Adding an Image to a sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, blob

I've been struggling for a while now with this, and i want to be able to store an image to my database. I know storing an image to a database directly is bad practice but i simply do not know enough to be able to do it another way.

So, i'm currently stuck with a few issues.

Firstly, I'm not even sure my path is correct; i want to get a drawable file and store it to my database and there must be an easier way than doing a path straight from the C drive right?

Secondly, I don't know much about this but i need to convert my file to a bitmap so that it can be converted to a byte array? And i'm not sure how to do this exactly.

I've tried several things, wrote this code out about 10 times already in different ways and not getting anywhere. Thanks all for help in advance.

```
   public void insertAvatar(String Email, byte[] head) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Avatar VALUES (?, ?)";

    File head = new File("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\capaa\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\head2.png");
    Bitmap imageToStoreBitmap = head; // doesn't work as my file isnt a bitmap yet
    objectByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    imageToStoreBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, objectByteArrayOutputStream);
    imageInBytes = objectByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    contentValues.put("Email", Email);
    contentValues.put("head", imageInBytes);
    long checkIfQueryRuns = db.insert("Avatar", null, contentValues );
}
```

Comment: why you put Android  tag, does this code run on Android ?!

Comment: Yeah its for my android app :)

Comment: when the code run on Android on your phone , it will not have access to the file you are specifying here, put your file on an SD card or on your pictures folder .... and use the path in your Android phone(ex: /storage/sdcard0/...) and not of your windows computer (c:\....)

Comment: Is there no other way to do this? Say you had to use several devices, it would be long winded to transfer the images to each device.

Comment: yes , you can install a server on your pc , and fetch images from that server

Comment: ahh but that isnt sqlite is it, don't think that would work for me

Comment: if you need to put images in a database you can encode them into base64 and put them as string, to display them pull them and then decode them

Comment: The Android device will likely not have acces to "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\capaa\\src\\main\\res\\drawable\\head2.png", that is it is very likely a file on the PC. The head2.png will be an Android RESOURCE as far as the device is concerned. See [App resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources)

Comment: Why do you want to save images in the database?

Comment: I was looking to create a sort of character so that when the app loads, it can get the correct images from the database. I've created a sort of shop that changes items on my character and i needed the images to be saved to a database so that when the app is closed, the images bought can be saved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use  Blob to store images in your SQLite database.

Create a table to store the images

```
CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE_NAME + "("+ 
                   KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + 
                   KEY_IMAGE + " BLOB);";
```

To store an image in the table

```
public void addImage( String name, byte[] image) throws SQLiteException{
    ContentValues cv = new  ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME,    name);
    cv.put(KEY_IMAGE,   image);
    database.insert( DB_TABLE_NAME, null, cv );
}
```

As you can see before inserting the image to the table, you need to convert the bitmap to a byte array.

```
// To convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getImageBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}
```

To retrieve image from database

```
//search your image using the key and get the cursor
............
byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);
............
```

As you can see the image returned is in a byte array. Now you can convert this byte array to bitmap to use in your app.

```
//To convert from byte array to bitmap
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

Having written the answer, I myself is not a big fan of storing images in the database. I am not sure what is your need for storing the images but you can check the following libraries to handle images in your app.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/

https://square.github.io/picasso/

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) I have one question though, you know the `add image` method, where does it pulls the image from? Assuming you have to declare a path or something? I've seen lots of tutorials of people selecting images from the device to save to db, but this is not what i want. The code you've done is what im looking for, although i need to add a specific image to the db, rather than an image being passed into the `add image`. See how i've done in my example with the `File head`.

Comment: And i know its not best practice to add images straight to the db, but i'm a bit of a noob when it comes to android so not sure of any other SIMPLE way. I do appreciate your response though :)

Comment: what do you want to do in your app?